# Find the Big-O of the modular algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o

```
i=1
while i <= n do:
   j=0
   k=i
   while k%3 == 0 do:
      k = k/3
      j++
   end

   print i, j
   i++
end
```

What is **Big-O** of given algorithm (How do we show my work)? And **what does this algorithm output** // ?

My answer and approach

`O(nlogn)`. Because the outer loop runs linear time as O(n) while the inner loop is dependent as `O(logn)`.

But I'm not sure if it's `logn`.

When n = 10,

```
ij
00
10
20
31
40
50
61
70
80
92
100 ( 10, 0)
```

When n = 30

```
i j
1 0
2 0
3 1
4 0
5 0
6 1
7 0
8 0
9 2
10 0
11 0
12 1
13 0
14 0
15 1
16 0
17 0
18 2
19 0
20 0
21 1
22 0
23 0
24 1
25 0
26 0
27 3
28 0
29 0
30 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Appreciate that every third number in the series from `1` to `n` will be divisible by 3.  In the worst case, such a number would end up being divided by 3 in the `k` loop `log_3(i)` times.  So the sequence will behave like `O(n)` two thirds of the time, and like `O(n*log3(n))` one third of the time.  We can therefore claim that your code is upper bounded by `O(n*log3(n))`, although there is a bound which is tighter than this.

The code will print each value `i` in the series along with the "three depth" of that number.  By "three depth" I mean how many times we were able to divide `i` by 3.  Obviously, for `i` values which are not multiples of 3, the depth is 0.

Comment: While that is an upper bound, the tighter bound is relatively trivial to compute. The number of iterations of the inner loop required is 1 for each value assigned to i, and 1 more for every 3 values, and 1 more for every 9 values ... This is n multiplied by the geometric series (1 + 1/3 + 1/9 + 1/27 ...). That's just 1.5n - so this would just be O(n).